'Cloning' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
I run flutter with android emulator but when I run it, it gives an error like this:

'Cloning' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Does anyone have the same problem? and how to solve it?
